# Setting a repeating Alarm by using services

Tags: android, alarm

As i want to implement the set repeat alarm in my project,I didn't get proper code.Please suggest some links.

I referred many links, but just single alarm only showing selecting date and time.

Even application in background also i want to implement the alarm repeat.

[image]

Attached images

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide days selector. Like in the screenshot you shared above. As you may basically want to ring the alarm at the same time every day after selecting time. Give the options to select which days the alarm should ring.

In case they want the alarm at a different time, they will have to add a new alarm and will again have the option to select days.

If you are not sure how to configure alarm manager for repeating alarms please check this documentation https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms